# Faking a HttpRequest

Tags: c#, httprequest

My web application has a HttpHandler that takes in some XML (request message) via HTTP POST, that does something with it and that then returns some other XML back (response message). But one of the parties that is sending me the XML is now insisting they do this over SOAP in stead of HTTP POST. The fact that it is becoming SOAP is not very important, it just adds some tags around the initial payload. Let's just receive the data, transform the message back into what it was before, and deliver it to the original HttpHandler...

So first, the message that I used to get in my HttpHandler was like

```
<placeorder>
    <products>
        <product>123</product>
        <product>123</product>
    </products>
</placeorder>
```

And now the message that I get in my SoapService is like

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <placeorder>
            <products>
                <product>123</product>
                <product>123</product>
            </products>
        </placeorder>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

In order not to change too much code, I thought about just writing a method `placeorder` in a SoapService asmx, that has a parameter `products`. It will fake a HttpRequest and pass it to my original HttpHandler.

```
public class SoapService : WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public XmlDocument placeorder(XmlDocument products)
    {
        var hrq = new HttpRequest(null, "http://dummy/dummy", null);
        var requestString = "<placeorder><products>";
        requestString += products.DocumentElement.OuterXml;
        requestString += "</products></placeorder>";
        /* this line is failing */ hrq.InputStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestString), 0, requestString.Length);
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        var sw = new StreamWriter(ms);
        var hrs = new HttpResponse(sw);
        var hc = new HttpContext(hrq, hrs);
        var mhh = new MyHttpHandler();
        mhh.ProcessRequest(hc); // finally execute my original code
        var responseString = hc.Response.OutputStream.ToString();
        var externalResponse = new XmlDocument();
        externalResponse.LoadXml(responseString);
        return externalResponse;
    }
}
```

This all works except for the part where the payload (requestString) is written to the InputStream of the faked HttpRequest. The stream does not support writing to it. BUt I also cannot set the stream when constructing the HttpRequest. And I cannot use another stream to replace it, since the property is read-only.

So how can I accomplish setting the InputStream of creating a HttpRequest?

Comment: The request's InputStream is a forward only/read only stream, you can't write to it. You are going to have to modify your ProcessRequest method to handle extracting the xml fragment you are interested in before processing it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to not fake http and just break out the code handling the data to a specific method and call it from both the HTTP-post handler and the SOAP handler?

Comment: @Jonny True, but I would rather prevent having to open a new connection to localhost just to accomplish something that will run in the application itself. Surely there is a way I can also create a HttpContext/HttpRequest without truly having to execute one.

Comment: I'm not saying add a connection. I'm saying you should run the same code no matter which interface the request came from.